# How to split an array with a separator and a limit in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My intention is to split an array using a separator and choose a limit of its splitting.

```js
var arr = [89, 'sdf', 0, null, 0, true, 89, 0, 'sdf'];
var res = [];
while (arr.length) {
  res.push(arr.splice(0, 2));
}
console.log(res)
```

For example: If `0` is the separator and `2` is the limit

```
arr.split(0, 2)
[[89, 'sdf'], [null]] //output
```

Comment: why is the zero gone?

Comment: Why do you keep `null` but remove `0`?

Comment: @NinaScholz this is because he wants to split the array using 0 as delimiter

Comment: How does this work?? Shouldn't it be `[[89, "sdf"], [0, true]]`?

Comment: The idea is to use the 0 as the separator and output to be [[89, 'sdf'], [null]] if user choose to split the array like this arrat.split(0, 2) or array.separate(0, 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and `splice` like this:

```js
var arr = [89, 'sdf', 0, null, 0, true, 89, 0, 'sdf'];

function splitArray(arr, seperator, count) {
  let result = [], 
        copy = arr.slice(), // if you don't want to mutate the original array
        counter = 0;
  
  while(counter < count && copy.length > 0) {
    const index = copy.indexOf(seperator);
    if(index !== - 1) {
      result.push(copy.splice(0, index));
      copy.shift(); // remove the seperator
    }
    else result.push(copy.splice(0)) // add the remaining items

    counter++
  }
  
  return result
}

console.log(splitArray(arr, 0, 2))
console.log(splitArray(arr, 0, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and take a counter, which works as index for the result array and push the item into the result array of the counter.

```js
function split(array, length, separator) {
    var result = [],
        count = 0,
        i = 0;

    while (count < length && i < array.length) {
        if (array[i] === separator) {
            count++;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        result[count] = result[count] || [];
        result[count].push(array[i++]);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(split([89, 'sdf', 0, null, 0, true, 89, 0, 'sdf'], 2, 0));
```

Version with `indexOf` and `slice`.

```js
function split(array, length, separator) {
    var result = [],
        p,
        i = 0;

    while ((p = array.indexOf(separator, i)) !== -1 && result.length < length) {
        result.push(array.slice(i, p));
        i = p + 1;
    }
    if (result.length < length) result.push(array.slice(i));
    return result;
}

console.log(split([89, 'sdf', 0, null, 0, true, 89, 0, 'sdf'], 2, 0));
console.log(split([89, 'sdf', 0, null, 0, true, 89, 0, 'sdf'], 5, 0));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ah smart and simple, I wrote a solution using serialization, split, trim, deserialization, but good old loops will easier do the job

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one

```
var arrays = [], size = 2;

var arr = [89, 'sdf', 0, null, 0, true, 89, 0, 'sdf'];
while (arr.length > 0)
    arrays.push(arr.splice(0, size));
```